# How to convert an array of characters into a string in Studio 5000 Logix Designer ladder logic

Tags: arrays, plc, ladder-logic

I have a barcode scanner that communicates with a 1756-L75 ControlLogix PLC over RS232.

The data from the scanner is read in byte by byte and stored in a `SINT` array as characters. It includes a header and the barcode data. The barcode data is variable in length.

I need to convert this array of characters into a proper `STRING` datatype.

I know that I can copy the array into the data portion of the string, but I'm looking for the best way to fill in the length.

Is there a built-in instruction that will automatically do that or will I need calculate it?

Answer (score 1):

My current (untested) solution is as follows.

I'm assuming that the character array and the string are cleared before data is read.

1. Execute an `FSC` (File Search and Compare).

   - Here I've populated the `.LEN` with the size of the character array. This ensures that the instruction will search to the end of the array.
   - Search for the first element that is still null
   - The `FSC` will report the **index** of the element it finds. This equals the **length** of the actual data.

```
 char  -> 'd' 'a' 't' 'a' $00 $00
 index ->  0   1   2   3   4   5
                           ^
.POS = 4
```

2. Move the `FSC` result (`.POS`) into the string's `.LEN`
3. Copy the characters to the string data
4. Do what you need with the data, then clear the character array, clear the string, and reset the `FSC` to get ready for the next barcode.

[image: screenshot of ladder logic]

Note that logic preceding these instructions has been stripped in an effort to reduce clutter so assume that this only executes for one scan after a barcode is read. You may also need additional logic if it's possible for the barcode data to completely fill the character array.